# What causes varying degrees of recall of text when speaking aloud versus mentally?

Tags: memory

**Background:** When i try to recall some memorised passages from a book, I find that some memories are best recalled when i speak aloud and some when i speak inaudibly in my mind.

**What causes varying degrees of recall of text when speaking aloud versus mentally?**